# Why mysql workbench 8.0 is throwing error for not closing if's, though all "if's" are closed properly?

Tags: mysql

Though my procedure code has proper "if"s (that is "if"s that are opened and closed properly), mysql workbench 8.0 is throwing an error that all "if"s are not closed properly. I can't find any other mistake too. Please help me out.

If I am adding extra "if"s in the end, the errors are gone. But it is not correct since those "end if"s do not have any if so that they can be closed.Though it is not showing any error, while applying the procedure with the additional "end if"s, it is not getting applied instead throws some other error.

```
IF(Ser ='search') THEN

        IF(Value = 0) THEN

            IF EXISTS(SELECT Role FROM U WHERE Name = name) THEN

                IF(O = 0) THEN

                    IF(F1 <> NULL AND F1V <> NULL AND 
                        F2 = NULL AND F2V = NULL
                        ) THEN


                        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Com ) THEN

                            SET V=0;

                        END IF;

                    ELSE IF (F1<> NULL AND F1V <> NULL AND 
                            F2 <> NULL AND F2V <> NULL
                            ) THEN

                        IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Com ) THEN

                                                        SET V=1;

                        END IF;

                    END IF;

                ELSE IF(O = 1) THEN

                                SET A=0;

                     END IF;

        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

Comment: Can you try `elseif(var=1) then` instead of `else if(var=1) then` ?

Comment: I tried but throws syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the else if condition to if and it started working.